# Installing pip in Pycharm 2016.3

Tags: python, bash, pip, pycharm

I upgraded to the new version of Pycharm. In the terminal, it says `bash-3.2$` instead of my username. When I tried to install a library, it said that pip command is not found:

```
bash: pip: command not found
```

So I installed pip:

```
bash-3.2$ sudo easy_install pip
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 8.1.2
pip 8.1.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip3.5 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip3 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip</i>
```

Okay, now all I have to do is use pip to install a library, right?

But then, this happens:

```
bash-3.2$ pip install pandas
bash: pip: command not found
```

I don't understand what I have to do to actually install pip. Or should I use `sudo easy_install [library]`?

Comment: The latest installations of Python have pip already...

Comment: If a command isn't found, thats a `PATH` problem, not really PyCharm

Comment: Are you on mac OS X to linux??and do `pip3` bring the same error?

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is not precisely what you're asking, but PyCharm has its own built-in package manager.  You should not have to use pip manually.

File->Settings->Project Interpreter
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

there you can manage the installed packages for the selected Python interpreter or virtualenv.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I was having a hard time doing the installing and stuff, but now i've resolve th

Answer (score 1):

Run this command on your terminal. pip will be installed without any issue.

```
sudo [your package manager] install python-pip python-dev build-essential
```

If it is not solved. The problem might be `PATH` problem.
Type `echo $PATH` on terminal. There should be `/usr/local/bin` in the output. If it is not type `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` to add `/usr/local/bin` to `PATH`