# Library package not in module PyCharm, even though I've already installed it

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, simplecv, quandl

So I wanted to use the Quandl package to learn some data processing.
I installed Quandl in the PyCharm package, and it worked out pretty well.

```
import  Quandl, math
```

and then, I use the Quandl to get some data from the internet

```
data = Quandl.get('some form of data')
```

But then when I tried to run the python script

```
bash-3.2$ python Regression.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Regression.py", line 2, in <module>
    import  Quandl, math
ImportError: No module named Quandl
```

In my PyCharm interpreter, I have 4 different types:

-*2.7.11 (/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7)*
I installed Quandl here

-*3.5.1 (/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5)*
I also installed it here

-*2.6.9 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6)*
It has an error to install packaging tools

-*/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7*
Permission denied for installing

When I tried to import Quandl in the terminal through python shell, I also retired an error

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Quandl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Quandl
```

I also tried the same thing for Simple CV, it also says that it's not in the module, even though I've already installed it both in 3.5 and 2.7.

```
from SimpleCV import Camera

cam = Camera()

while True:

    img = cam.getImage()

    img = img.binarize()

    img.drawText("Hello World")

    img.show()


bash-3.2$ python simplecv.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simplecv.py", line 1, in <module>
    from SimpleCV import Camera
ImportError: No module named SimpleCV
```

For installing 'pip', I also had an error installing it in the PyCharm terminal. I've already asked a question about it [Installing pip in Pycharm 2016.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41073620/installing-pip-in-pycharm-2016-3/41075237#41075237)

Comment: You'll need to install it in the interpreter you're using: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Quandl

Comment: you may have many Python versions installed and PyCharm may use different Python than you use in console. Every version use only own modules so you have to install `Quandl` in both version.

Comment: In my Pycharm interpreter, i have 4 different types:

Answer (score 0):

Try going to your command prompt and typing:

```
pip install quandl
```

might not work if you don't have pip, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

use `import quandl` instead of `import Quandl`.
I was facing similar problem with Quandl.